# Problema con mandar información a través de una variable en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola buenas tardes o noches.

Tengo una duda/problema para asignar un valor a una variable, presento el caso:

Tengo un modelo que se llama DeudaCompleta y  dentro de este tengo definidos 3 objetos:

- public Oferta DetalleOferta {get;set;}
- public List DetalleRutero {get;set;}
- public List Detalle Cuotas {get;set;}

Cada uno ya tiene definido su modelo con sus variables correspondientes.

Este lo uso dentro de la siguiente función:

```
public DeudaCompleta ConsultaOferta(string rut, int plazo, string oferta,string tipoOferta)
{
    DeudaCompleta deuda = new DeudaCompleta();

    RenegociacionBLL.Reneg objBll = new RenegociacionBLL.Reneg();
    DataSet dsDeuda = objBll.GeneraReneg(rut,plazo,oferta,tipoOferta);

    DataTable dtVenta = dsDeuda.Tables["Table_Reneg"];

    // cuando viene vacio
    if (dtVenta.Rows[0]["RutDeu"].ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        return deuda; 
    }

    //cuando venga con informacion
    DataTable dtOper = dsDeuda.Tables["Table_Origen"];
    DataTable dtCuotas = dsDeuda.Tables["Table_RenegCuotas"];

    // mucho codigo


    
    // después de muchas operaciones

    Venta detVenta = new Venta();
    detVenta.fechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
    detVenta.oferta = solDeuda.ofertaDescripcion;
    detVenta.rutCliente = solDeuda.rutCliente;

    deuda.DetalleOferta = detOfeta;     // esta variable se definen en otra parte
    deuda.DetalleRutero = listaRutero;  // esta variable se definen en otra parte
    deuda.DetalleCuotas = listaCuotas;  // esta variable se definen en otra parte

    return deuda;
}
```

No puse todo el código para que no sea tan largo, necesito que se entienda la idea. Las variables del final estas ya están inicializadas y tienen sus valores que se asignan según corresponda a deuda.DetalleOferta, deuda.DetalleRutero y deuda.DetalleCuotas.

Así yo después tomo la variable deuda y puedo entrar a sus variables internas, por dar un ejemplo:

string stri = deuda.DetalleOferta.exclusion.ToString();

El punto es que necesito controlar cuando **DataSet dsDeuda = objBll.GeneraReneg(rut,plazo,oferta,tipoOferta);** venga vacío, en realidad no viene completamente vacío, pongo una imagen:

[image: imagen1]

La columna Observación y Exclusión no lo están y necesito cargarle el valor de la Exclusión a mi variable Deuda

Tendría que hacerlo dentro del if:

```
if (dtVenta.Rows[0]["RutDeu"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
   // esta ruta está bien es donde tiene que estar
   deuda.DetalleOferta.Exclusion = dtVenta.Rows[0]["Exclusion"].ToString();
   return deuda; 
}
```

Mi problema, es que como esta función devuelve este valor a otra función, a la otra función no le gusta lo que le devuelve.

El mensaje de la excepción es: "Referencia a un objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Esto se debe a que ¿no estoy inicializando bien la variable deuda? o estoy haciendo otra cosa mal?.

Necesito un poco de guía con esto.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si. es lo que decis.. una de tus variables es null.. solo depurando te vas a dar cuenta cual...

Comment: Creo que lo que decis variables son atributos de la clase Deuda?... el dataset dsDeuda; lo puedes verificar si esta sin filas de esta forma  "if (dsDeuda.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)" en algún lugar asignando algo al objeto objBll.GeneraReneg, o en el llamado de la función esta llegando algun dato de los parámetros que indicaste rut,plazo,oferta,tipoOferta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que una propiedad está siendo `null`.

De acuerdo a lo que has publicado tenemos lo siguiente:

```cs
public class DeudaCompleta
{
   public Oferta DetalleOferta { get; set;}
   public List DetalleRutero { get; set;}
   public List DetalleCuotas { get; set;}
}

public class Oferta 
{
   public string Exclusion {get; set;}
}
```

Parece ser que el método `ConsultaOferta` se encarga de llenar una instancia de `DeudaCompleta`. Vamos a anlizar el flujo:

Creas una instancia:

```cs
DeudaCompleta deuda = new DeudaCompleta();
```

Hasta este momento, las propiedades de deuda son nulas (`DetalleOferta`, `DetalleRutero`, `DetalleCuotas`)

y por eso les asignas un valor al final, haciendo que contengan un objeto:

```cs
deuda.DetalleOferta = detOfeta;  
deuda.DetalleRutero = listaRutero;
deuda.DetalleCuotas = listaCuotas;
```

Sin embargo, parece ser que la quieres llenar de una manera diferente dependiendo de una condición.

```cs
if (dtVenta.Rows[0]["RutDeu"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
   deuda.DetalleOferta.Exclusion = dtVenta.Rows[0]["Exclusion"].ToString();
   return deuda; 
}
```

El problema es que `deuda.DetalleOferta` es `null` (no le has asignado ningún objeto), por lo que tendrías que hacer es asignarle uno:

```cs
if (dtVenta.Rows[0]["RutDeu"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
   // Creas un objeto oferta para asignarle un valor a su propiedad Exclusion
   Oferta oferta = new Oferta();
   oferta.Exclusion = dtVenta.Rows[0]["Exclusion"].ToString();

   // Asignas el objeto oferta a la propiedad DetalleOferta del objeto deuda
   deuda.DetalleOferta = oferta;
   return deuda; 
}
```

Pero recuerda que `DetalleRutero` y `DetalleCuotas` siguen siendo `null`. Quizá alguna cause algún problema.

Podrías evitar el tener que crear objetos cada vez, inicializando un valor por default.

```cs
public class DeudaCompleta
{
   public Oferta DetalleOferta { get; set;}
   public List DetalleRutero { get; set;}
   public List DetalleCuotas { get; set;}

   public DeudaCompleta()
   {
      DetalleOferta = new Oferta();
      DetalleRutero = new List();
      DetalleCuotas = new List();
   }
}
```

Lo cual se puede sintetizar en C#6 +:

```
public class DeudaCompleta
{
   public Oferta DetalleOferta { get; set;} = new Oferta();
   public List DetalleRutero { get; set;} = new List();
   public List DetalleCuotas { get; set;} =  new List();
}
```

Así, podrías realizar lo siguiente:

```cs
if (dtVenta.Rows[0]["RutDeu"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
   // DetalleOferta ya tiene un objeto, por lo que solo hay que settear su propiedad Exclusion 
   deuda.DetalleOferta.Exclusion = dtVenta.Rows[0]["Exclusion"].ToString();
   return deuda; 
}
```

Por último, considera que `detOfeta`, `listaRutero` y `listaCuotas` pueden ser null, por lo que si tomas este enfoque de que no existan `null`, deberías de agregar una validación antes de asignarlos a `deuda`.

Sin embargo si el que las propiedades sean `null` te sirve para algo en la lógica, entonces no te funcionaría este enfoque y tendrías que agregar validaciones a quienes utilicen el método `ConsultaOferta` para que no ocurra una excepción.

Comment: excelente respuesta.. pero esta pregunta es un duplicado de una canonica que explica que hay que hacer en estos casos... por los comentarios que se dejaron yo por lo menos estaba esperando para cerrarla por ese motivo...

Comment: hola, buenos días. voy a probar lo que me dices y comento. muchas gracias

Comment: me funcionó,! muchas gracias